# Partition function for two systems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

**The goal**. Calculate the partition function of the following systems:

- A gas of $N$ non-interacting distinguishable particles with non-degenerate energy levels $E_0=0$ and $E_1=\epsilon$;
- A chain of $N$ sites that can be either open ($E=\epsilon>0$) or closed ($E=0$) such that if the $i$-th element is open, then all elements $j<i$ are open.

---

**First system**. if $k$ particles are in the excited state, the corresponding microstate has total energy $E_k=k\epsilon$. There are $\binom{N}{k}$ ways to choose such $k$ particles out of the $N$ particles in the gas; the remaining $N-k$ particles are then fixed at energy $E_0=0$. Therefore in total
$$Z=\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{N}{k} \exp(-\beta k\epsilon)=\sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k} [\exp(-\beta \epsilon)]^k=[1+\exp(-\beta\epsilon)]^N.$$
**Second system**. if the rightmost open link is at position $0<k<N$, we get a microstate with energy $E=k\epsilon$, same as above. On the other hand, there is now no degeneracy on microstates. In total,
$$Z=\sum_{k=0}^N\exp(-\beta k\epsilon)=\sum_{k=0}^N[\exp(-\beta\epsilon)]^k=\frac{1-e^{-(N+1)\beta\epsilon}}{1-e^{-\beta\epsilon}}.$$

Is everything I've done above correct?

Comment: Why are you not summing only j < k ? The other terms give 1 N-k times, and then you have the sum I referred to...
Also, this should be tagged as homework

Comment: Hi daydreamer. First, please note I have edited my answer due to $2$ mistakes: there was no degeneracy on the chain microstates, and the geometric series was applied incorrectly. I think the solution should be correct now. I am not summing over $j<k$ because $k$ indexes the whole chain, from $1$ to $N$.

Comment: You're right. It is all good now. Best regards